# Thursday incorrectly returning Tuesday when trying to get day of week

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

I am getting very strange behavior using momentjs:

```
moment().day('Thursday').format('e') // Should return '4' but is returning '2'
```

All other weekdays are correct. When I specifically put in a date which lands on a Thursday:

```
moment('2020-03-26').day() // I correctly get '4'
```

I am also utilizing moment-range but have never had this behavior before. I am not mutating the object in any way that would create this offset that I can think of, and have no custom locale settings.

I can't replicate this issue a sandbox, so I believe it must be something within my environment I am wondering if anyone has any ideas or has come up against an issue like this because I've tried different options/settings and nothing changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try sourcing from one of the [CDN](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/moment)

I'm guessing there's something wrong with your package version? I can't replicate your issue, and I tried the CDN's js file.

Comment: Well it worked, thank you...the CDN is the same as the npm version (2.24.0) I'm using in my Vue project, so I am still confused where the discrepancy is coming from. I am trying to find an option where I don't have to replace it everywhere with the CDN because it's used extensively throughout the app...any thoughts?

Comment: Although it sounds tacky as heck I suggest deleting the file npm installed and replacing it with a wget of the CDN's file.

You may have some issues with the package lock stuff from the npm side of things, though.